# Windows Server 2012 Remotedesktop: connect to a specific session host

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, rds

in my test enviroment I have four remotedesktop session hosts and one broker.

Now I want to install software on each sesion host.
When I connect with the local administrator, it's all fine, but I have to logon with the domain administrator.

If I logon with the domain administrator my rds session is redirected to a random session host - bad for me, because I have to install something.

Is there a way to do a exciplit connect to a session host without activate login-lock of the other hosts?

I am grateful for every advice!

Comment: I'm assuming you're connecting to the farm name. Have you tried connecting to the individual ip addresses or the individual names of each server.

Comment: @joeqwerty Session hosts know that they are part of a farm, and in this case may redirect the incoming session after consulting with the broker server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your remote desktop client use the `/admin`switch, depending on the client to connect to the console session of the terminal server.

The console session is immune from redirection by a session broker.

Ref: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/use-command-line-parameters-with-remote-desktop-connection

> /admin
>
> Is used for administration of a terminal server. In this version of
>   Remote Desktop Connection, if the Terminal Server role service is
>   installed on the remote computer, running mstsc /admin will do the
>   following (for the current connection only):
>
> - Disable Terminal Services client access licensing.
> - Disable time zone redirection.
> - **Disable TS Session Broker redirection.**
> - Disable TS EasyPrint.
>
> /admin also does the following on connections to Windows Server 2008
>   with the Terminal Server role service installed:
>
> - Disables Plug and Play device redirection for this connection only.
> - Changes the remote session theme to Windows Classic View for this connection only.
>
> To connect to a remote computer with the Terminal Server role service
>   installed, follow these steps:
>
> - Open the Command Prompt window by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, and
>     then clicking Command Prompt.
> - Type mstsc /v:server /admin.

Answer (score 1):

Connect directly to the session host instead of using the farm hostname which points to the broker.

or

Connect to each server via an out-of-band console (IP KVM, iLO, DRAC, vSphere Client, etc)

or

Script and deploy software centrally so that you can ensure that your user experience is identical across all servers. Manually installing things can lead to human errors and misconfiguration. If you have SCCM or similar software, use that, if not, you can use Group Policy Software Deployment or a startup script in a pinch.

Comment: I'm using the IP-Adress of this server i want to connect to, but I'm redirected to another host every time.